# Adding Event Handler in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, imagebutton

How to add event handler to image button in ASP.NET ? IS it possible to add event handler just like we do in WPF ? Help please .

Answer (score 1):

The easy way: Just double click your image button.

The almost as easy way: Right click your image button, select Properties. From Properties click the lightning bolt icon at the top. Here you can access all your Events, double click the one you want to handle and it automatically creates an event handler method for you to customise.